# Visual Studio Code Ethereum tutorial

Tags: solidity, contract-development, visual-studio-code

Are there any tutorials on how to use MS Visual Studio Code to write contracts in solidity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure on specific VS tutorials, but this is a generic tutorial for solidity:
http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

which should work on: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/96221853-33c4-4531-bdd5-d2ea5acc4799

Comment: Thanks Nikhil this will do for now, though I hoped to get a video tutorial

Answer (score 16):

For Visual Studio Code, there is an extension which provide syntax highlighting.
[image: Installing solidity in visual studio code]

To install:

Press Ctrl + P and type "ext install ". Note: The trailing space.
Type "Solidity", click in the extension and you are done.

You can find it also in the [Visual Studio Code Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity)

This is an example using the Theme Dark+
[image: Using visual studio code with solidity]

**Note:** The bug on the Linux version of Visual Studio Code, has been fixed in the latest version. Many thanks to @dotnetjunkie for your help.

To install the latest version:

- Press F1
- Type ext update
- Select solidity

More info on the fix here: [Syntax highlighting for Solidity VS Code extension not working on linux](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2776/syntax-highlighting-for-solidity-vs-code-extension-not-working-on-linux)

Comment: Hey Juan... I did install the extension although its not looking colorful as yours

Comment: Change your theme to Dark+, go to File -> Preferences -> Themes ->Dark+

Comment: Still no difference. My file is saves with the .sol extension as well but nothing is happening

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code? or Visual Studio? The OP is for visual studio code... but the accepted answer points to the extension of Visual Studio (just checking we are talking about the same thing :) )

Comment: Yes I am using Visual Studio Code Version 0.10.11. Check it out here -> [url=http://postimg.org/image/w0d18qr0j/]

Comment: ah great, if you press F1 again and type ext, you will have an option to see installed extensions. It might not installed correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37818/discussion-between-juan-blanco-and-kizito).

Comment: @JuanBlanco With the latest VS Code, it cannot find the Solidity extension, any ideas?

Comment: @JuanBlanco Nevermind, Looks like I had an ancient VS Code

Comment: @JuanBlanco thanks for the extention but on windows and VS Code I am currently experiencing an issue command "solidity.compile.active" not found, I havent installed any command line tools, should I install any command line extensions?

Answer (score 2):

You can find a tutorial for this on [my msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/caleteet/2016/04/01/solidity-integration-with-visual-studio/).

Also some quick videos on this as well:

- [Installing the VSIX package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9SCBAAb24s&feature=youtu.be)
- [How to use the tooling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoffoNRk-Xg&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Typically on StackExchange, we prefer to not have "link-only" answers. However, since the poster was literally asking for this, I'm not sure how to handle it. Please, don't make a habit of this & if you could possibly expand on your answer (what does the tutorial cover, etc) that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Hi the OP refers to Visual Studio Code not Visual Studio there is another Q&A for that http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/how-to-install-solidity-in-visual-studio/2495, you should add that info on the other post, good tutorial :)

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum! A link alone is not considered a [good answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Links may break and the answer becomes worthless later even if the linked material answered the question initially. At least if you [include a summary](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), the answer can somewhat stand on its own.