# Syntax highlighting for Solidity VS Code extension not working on linux

Tags: solidity, linux, visual-studio-code

Even if the extension installation completes correctly, syntax highlighting does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that the syntax highlighting bug for Solidity VS Code Extension on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 in my case) is due to a wrong configuration of the extension itself. To fix it and get correct highlighting you just have to change the case of a letter in the package.json file you find in:

```
[your home]/.vscode/extensions/JuanBlanco.solidity-0.0.1/package.json
```

Just check the grammar section of the json file and change the value of the "path" property:

Original (wrong) value: `./syntaxes/solidity.tmLanguage`

Correct value: `./syntaxes/Solidity.tmLanguage`

Please note the upper case of 'S'.

Now it works fine! Thanks Juan for creating it!!

Answer (score 2):

The release 0.0.2 fixes the issue thanks to @dotnetjunkie

To install the latest version:

- Press F1
- Type ext update
- Select solidity

Answer (score 0):

Delete other extentions like solidity-solhint